# How do I make SVG created shapes responsive to any screen size?

Tags: html, css, svg, screen

I have coded 2 circles that appear on the corners of a screen with a '+' in the middle. However, as I change screens, the circles and '+' don't modify to fit the dimensions of a new screen

I've looked at questions that've been asked here before in regards to this topic, and this is what I have found helpful. Yet, the objects inside the svg are still not responsive to a change in screen size

```
<html style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<body style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:20;">
<svg width="1380" height="820">
```

```css
 .fade-out {
  animation: hide 3s ease-in forwards;
}
@keyframes hide {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 0.5; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<body style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:20;">
<!-- defines dimensions of svg screen-->
<svg width="100vw" height="100vh" > 
<!-- creates greyscale gradient and attached it to dot 2 (top right)-->
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="dot2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:grey;stop-opacity:0.5" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:black;stop-opacity:0.9" />
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="shadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="0.9" dy="0.9" stdDeviation="0.4"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="1350" cy="40" r="25" fill="url(#dot2)" filter="url(#shadow)" class="fade-out" />

  <!-- creates greyscale gradient and attaches it to dot 3 (bottom left)-->
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="dot3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:grey;stop-opacity:0.5" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:black;stop-opacity:0.9" />
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="shadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="0.9" dy="0.9" stdDeviation="0.4"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="40" cy="780" r="25" fill="url(#dot3)" filter="url(#shadow)" class="fade-out" />
<text x="670" y="440" style="fill:grey;stroke:black;opacity:0.9" font-size="100">+</text>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: max-width:100%;height:auto; applied to the svg. Remove the width and height properties from the svg.

Comment: Remove the width and height and add a viewBox attribute, for example `<svg viewBox="0 0 1400 820" >` Also you have a typo: a dot (.) before the `@keyframes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using direct pixel sizes such as 1380, do relative sizes like 100vw and 100vh. Such as:

```html
<svg width="100vw" height="100vh">
```

this will make it 100% of the view port width and 100% of the view port height

Comment: That would stretch the svg and look nasty af. https://codepen.io/anijack/pen/pXXOWx

Comment: @WizardCoder Your showing me a stretched image not a stretched SVG and if he wants it to be a circle or something then he can set the width equal to the height for a perfect circle

Comment: CSS has exactly the same effect on a flat image as it does to an svg.

Comment: @Stankeneddy774 it's a she, so you are saying that by simply changing the width and height, it will still appear on the screen?

Comment: @codebeginner1 well if you change the width and height to be relative to the size of your screen and not an absolute size of pixels then it'll fix the screen. What **exactly** are you trying to do

Comment: @Stankeneddy774 I just changed it to what you recommended and it works. What would I have to do to make sure the circle stays in the corner each time?

Comment: @codebeginner1 What do you mean by 'Make sure the circle stays in the corner each time'?

Comment: @Stankeneddy774 what I mean is for the 2 circles I've written in svg to stay in their relative positions no matter what the screen size is b/c right now they seem to not appear if the screen size is too small.

Comment: @codebeginner1 Is there a overflow-y and it's pushing the circles off the screen? If you turned off overflow-y you won't be able to see those circles further down in your page.